# HTML URL that triggers button click

Tags: javascript, html, copy

**Overview**:

I have a page where there is a button that copies something to clipboard.
[image]

**What I am trying to do:**

Instead of having to visit the page and click the button in order to copy the context, I want to have a link that would do that automatically. For example : www.link.com/#click_button

**Why is that?**

I am using a software where I have limitations. More specifically, I can only use HTML and CSS but not JS.

**HTML code in my page**:

```
<button class="buttons" id="copyButton2">Copy HTML Code</button>
```

**Idea**:

I cannot nest a `<button>` element in a URL.

The link in the software I am using will not redirect but it will trigger the action of the button.

I was thinking of adding an anchor that triggers the button click. And then use a link in the software with the link (that will include the anchor).

Comment: If `I can only use HTML and CSS but not JS. ` why did you tagged `javascript`?

Comment: @Ionut Because I will have to use JS in the page where the copy button is. I am trying to find a way to create an anchor that would copy a text without having to click the actual button. That is the first step. Then I should be able to create a link in the software that would not redirect me to the page but copy the text?